# How to restore PostgreSQL WAL from one Primary database to another Primary database nodes?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-13, postgresql-14

Suppose I have two separate primary database PrimaryDB1 and another is PrimaryDB2. I want all the transaction of PrimaryDB1 replicate into PrimaryDB2 by WAL replay. How can I do it?

I don't want other option like master, slave mode or primary/standby. I know it will works. Actually I want to replicate PrimaryDB1 to PrimaryDB2 ? Is it possible by WAL replay from one PrimaryDB1 to another PrimaryDB2. If possible then share me those steps. If WAL replay not possible then is there any other way to replicate from one master to another master.

Comment: You need [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html).

Comment: You are right I also found multimaster only support at  logical repliation.